# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) on SD card

Tags: java, android, sd-card, filewriter

I can't use FileWriter with a file on the SD card
I have the following permissions in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am using the following code

```
File selected = new File("/storage/extSdCard/", "00 - Copy.txt");
FileWriter fw;
try {
    fw = new FileWriter(selected, false);
    fw.write(content);
    fw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting the following in the logcat, knowing that /storage/extSdCard/00 - Copy.txt exists.

```
07-14 14:50:48.722  18216-19903/tk.hasankassem.supererase W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/extSdCard/00 - Copy.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-14 14:50:48.722  18216-19903/tk.hasankassem.supererase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
07-14 14:50:48.722  18216-19903/tk.hasankassem.supererase W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
07-14 14:50:48.722  18216-19903/tk.hasankassem.supererase W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
07-14 14:50:48.722  18216-19903/tk.hasankassem.supererase W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:96)
07-14 14:50:48.722  18216-19903/tk.hasankassem.supererase W/System.err﹕ at tk.hasankassem.supererase.MainActivity$5.run(MainActivity.java:302)
07-14 14:50:48.722  18216-19903/tk.hasankassem.supererase W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-14 14:50:48.722  18216-19903/tk.hasankassem.supererase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-14 14:50:48.722  18216-19903/tk.hasankassem.supererase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
07-14 14:50:48.722  18216-19903/tk.hasankassem.supererase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
07-14 14:50:48.722  18216-19903/tk.hasankassem.supererase W/System.err﹕ ... 4 more
```

I have tried using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), but it didn't work too.

**UPDATE**
when I use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() it writes to Internal Storage and not to the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

The following permissions should be defined outside the `<application>` tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Are you testing on emulator or on real device ?

Comment: I am testing on real device (Samsung Galaxy Note 4, lollipop)

Comment: Try to make your own app directory/folder and save your file inside that directory and try to access it.

Comment: still facing same issue in MI device. Please provide some solution for it